# how to work roundingMode in freemarker?

Tags: java, freemarker

I think it returns `1.13` but freemarker returns `1.12`.

**What is right?**

```
${(1.125)?string(",##0.00;roundingMode=HALF_UP")}
```

- freemarker version : 2.3.20

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 problems there:

- You need at least FreeMarker 2.3.24 to use "extended Java decimal format". It's a non-standard extension of `java.text.DecimalFormat` patterns, and as `DecimalFormat` is quite lenient, using it on an old versions will not result in error unfortunately, it's just being misinterpreted.
- You need two `;`-s, as the first one separtes the positive and negative number patterns.
- It's `halfUp`, not `HALF_UP`. (Using `HALF_UP` would give an error message, but as you are using a too old FreeMarker, the whole things is just silently ignored.)

**Update:** https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html#topic.extendedJavaDecimalFormat now warns users about the first two pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

Freemarker is correct, You probably misunderstood [HALF_EVEN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN), it is rounding to the **even** neighbor.

In your case 2 is even so 1.125 is rounded to 1.12.

> both neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even neighbor.

In freemarker [rounding constants](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html) are different:

> roundingMode   The value is one of up, down, ceiling, floor, halfUp, halfDown, halfEven, and unnecessary.

In your case you can use the following:

```
${(1.125)?string(",##0.00;; roundingMode=halfEven")}
```

Half even will be the default if you put none or irrelevant rounding

> Java default is halfEven

The fix was in version [2.3.24](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/versions_2_3_24). you should upgrade your version to get it working

> Everywhere where Java DecimalFormat patterns are used (like in ?string('0.##') or <#setting number_format="0.##">), now it's possible to specify options like rounding mode or the symbols used, with a FreeMarker-specific extension to the DecimalFormat pattern syntax.

Comment: How about "${(1.125)?string(",##0.00;roundingMode=HALF_UP")}" ? It also returns 1.12.

Comment: Do I have to check some configuration? ${(1.125)?string(",##0.00; roundingMode=halfEven")}
${(1.125)?string(",##0.00; roundingMode=halfUp")} . These two return 1.12 in my freemarker.

Comment: In my case, ${(1.125)?string(",##0.00; roundingMode=halfUp")}  ==> It also returns 1.12. Does it work well?

Comment: My mistake, we are missing extra `;` character. you should use: `${(1.125)?string(",##0.00;; roundingMode=halfUp")}`

Comment: Yah! It works at "http://try.freemarker.org/" Then it is version problem? Thank you so much!!

Comment: updated my answer. The fix was in version 2.3.24, you should upgrade your version to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The function HALF_EVEN is a rounding mode to round towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the **even neighbor**.

The even neighbor fro your number 1.125 is 1.2 and thus the mode is working fine. You can use HALF_UP to get the answer as 1.3

Comment: I changed to HALF_UP but it still returns 1.2 in my freemarker code.

Comment: Then I think, define the decimal format outside the template using Configuration.setNumberFormat(String) . Use it alternatively with <#setting number_format="0.##"> template and check for the results. Freemarker might be facing issues in reading the values after decimal.